# What could be the sense of an image loading once as background, and twice with an IMG tag?

Tags: html

Could somebody explain me, what could be the sense of this construction:

```
<div class="a" style="background-image: url('https://www.example.com/media/image.jpg')">
 <img src="https://www.example.com/media/image.jpg" class="b" alt="" title=""/>
</div>
```

If I inspect the code with DevTools or webpagetest.org I see the image loading only once, not twice, as I expected. Why is it so?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the specific browser implementation, but browsers that implement 5th version of HTML specification reuse images regardless of cache related HTTP headers, the first reference to the image to hit the server and when browser downloads first image source it adds it to list of available images using key and subsequent references and if browser sees another image with same key it will take it from a list of available images. So, only one network request for the image.

Comment: I mean rather: why one places one image over the same? Is this any html hint I dont know about?